# itemization in knitr with formulas in the middle

Tags: r, knitr

- I have something like this

  - then
  - a subset of bullets
    $$ 
    here I have an equation
    $$

-And then I would like to resume the last bullet list. But clearly it's not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
\begin{enumerate}
 \item A
 \begin{enumerate}
   \item A.1
   \item A.2
    $$2 + 2 = 4$$
   \item A.3
   \item A.4
 \end{enumerate}
 \item B
\end{enumerate}
```

This is the sintax for the R Markdown format:

```
- A
    - A.1
    - A.2
    $$2 + 2 = 4$$
    - A.3
    - A.4
- B
```

Use 4-space indents for the sublist. (https://code.google.com/p/pandoc/issues/detail?id=155)

Comment: I think that only works when compiling to pdf. I'm trying to compile to word and html.

Comment: Can you please tell me how you compile your .tex file into HTML or Word format?